# 3rd Party WSDL is Failing WSDL2Apex

Tags: soap-api, wsdl, wsdl2apex

I am migrating an application to the Salesforce environment. We have to make a soap call in order for the application to work appropriately. However, I have run into an issue with the vendors WSDL.

1. All of the schemas were separated out from the WSDL file, and they are large.
2. The wsdl file will not import into salesforce and continues to throw errors stating that it can't find elements.

### My approach

I intend to combine the WSDL and the schema into a single WSDL file, as well as add wsdl binding tags. Not sure if this is the best approach, but wanted to see if the community had information on the precise format that developers should follow when they get a bad WSDL from the vendor they are trying to integrate with.

### Documentation I have read thus far:

[Trailhead Integration Services](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_soap_callouts)

[Example WSDL](https://th-apex-soap-service.herokuapp.com/assets/calculator.xml?_ga=2.187201260.575216784.1615166003-65314459.1613772629)

[Salesforce developer guide on WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_gen_code.htm)

Comment: Long ago, in an API version far far away, I built a tool specifically to address this problem. It is an alternative version of WSDL2Apex that, among other  things, will try and pull in the schema files for you. See [An alternative to Salesforces Wsdl2Apex for calling SOAP web services in Apex](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/dreamforce-2014-presentation-improved.html). Try it as a first step. Depending on how complicated the WSDL is it might save you some time.

Comment: Thanks for the blog post. It confirms that Salesforce is not as concerned with their WSDL2Apex functionality. Appreciate your DreamForce lecture it was helpful.